# how to get triggerSuggest selected value in vscode extension develop

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension for myself to improve the efficiency of my coding.

But the poor API of vscode left me at a loss.
I expect to be able to capture the user's selection behavior and the selected values after executing the `triggerSuggest` command.
To provide me with the callback function.

Unfortunately, I didn't find the answer in the vscode documentation or online.
I hope someone can help me.

```
export default vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.snippets', async () => {
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.insertSnippet", {
        "langId": "typescript",
        "name": "xxx"
    })
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand("editor.action.triggerSuggest")
    // I cannot find the args of editor.action.triggerSuggest in the vscode documention
    // what should i do for capture user selected value and callback after select action

});
```

Comment: I doubt that's possible... What are you trying to accomplish with that? Maybe there's a different / better way to do it.

Comment: Actually, I still haven't found the answer. Maybe the CompletionItemProvider is a viable solution, but the CompletionItemProvider has too much distracting information